# Is it possible to configure IIS Worker Processes from C#

Tags: c#, iis

I'm creating a script that should configure a IIS server and I need to be able to increase the amount of worker processes.

I know it can be done with appcmd but it requires me to run the script from the server and that's not an option.

Is this task possible to do from C# Code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx

> The Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace contains classes that a
>   developer can use to administer IIS Manager... The classes in the
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace contain a series of convenient
>   top-level objects that allow the developer to perform administrative
>   tasks. The different logical objects available include sites,
>   applications, application pools, application domains, virtual
>   directories, and worker processes.